# Is there a limit on the number of USB devices you can plug into a laptop when using a USB hub?

Tags: usb

I'm fairly sure the answer is no... but had a few random issues recently when plugging in around 5 complex devices (i.e. hard drives, printers) into a laptop via a USB Hub when it already had about 5 dumb devices connected (chargers, keyboard, mouse etc.).

Some of the random issues I've noticed is that not all devices are picked up when plugged in via the USB Hub. The USB Hub seems to be limited to one or two complex devices and the other complex devices need to be plugged into their own USB directly on the laptop.

I'm trying to figure out if this is standard hardware behaviour or just a dodgy Chinese product from eBay :-D

Comment: The answer to your question is **a single host controller can support 127 USB devices**.  The actual limit of your hardware will be reached before that number though.  What the limit is depends on the power requirements of each device connected to the controller.

Comment: Looks like my gut feeling was correct, cheap product. Power is always going to be an issue unless devices have their own power supply, most of which would do for anything important though. The obvious next question would be... what counts as a Host Controller on a laptop - I'd assume a singe host controller on a laptop? Desktop setup would be 1x host controller = 1 PCIe card which is a fairly simple calculation.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate actually explains what a host controller is exactly.  The definition is identical for any (USB) host.

Comment: Is it a powered usb hub?

Comment: It is yes, but I'd imagine only limited power based on the tiny connector, so likely 2v at most.

Comment: USB supplies 5v. What is probably limited is the power; amperage.